# Understanding of Camera Up Vector

Tags: camera

Assume eye position e, gaze direction g, view-up vector t, right-handed base. As the graphs shows:
[image]
[image]

$w=-\frac{g}{||g||}$
$u=\frac{t\times w}{||t\times w||}$
$v=w\times u$

I am really confused about the 2nd equation $u=\frac{t\times w}{||t\times w||}$.
What if the camera rotate around its gaze direction? The v rotates while the t stays the same.
Then the vector t will not in the plane that w and v lies in which means the second equation is wrong.

I know I have something misunderstood.
Could someone please give me some clues?

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry. I have made a mistake. I have edited my question. "Then the vector t will not in the plane that w and u" should be "Then the vector t will not in the plane that w and v"

Comment: It isn't *supposed* to be in that plane. W is the direction of the view. V is supposed to be to the right of the view. If T is up, you can't have the right of the view in the same plane as up.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have added two pictures. The v here is top of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if the camera rotate around its gaze direction? The v rotates while the t stays the same.

The camera's orientation is defined by two directions: **g** and **t**. If the camera "rotates around its gaze direction", **g** will not be changing; that is what it means to "rotate around its gaze direction". If **g** isn't changing, and the camera's orientation is defined by two directions, then you can only get a different orientation if **t** is changing.

Therefore, your second statement is a contradiction of the first. Changing **t** is *precisely how* you cause the camera to "rotate around its gaze direction".

To put it a different way, there are changes to **t** which will *not* affect the values of **u**, **v**, or **w**. However, none of those changes will cause the camera to "rotate around its gaze direction".

Comment: I have seen many tutorials set t as Vector.up(0,1,0) in world space. So that only means the camera is put straight. The Vector.up(0,1,0) can't set up a camera with rotation around gaze direction. Have I understood your idea properly?

Comment: "If g isn't changing, and the camera's orientation is defined by two directions, then you can only get a different orientation if t is changing."  So if I want to set up a camera with rotation around gaze direction, the t should be set other than Vector.up(0,1,0)?